# How to Convert TimeStamp from md/dd/yyyy h:mm to DD/md/yyyy h:mm

Tags: ssis

I need help converting md/dd/yyyy h:mm to DD/md/yyyy h:mm
Example 11/12/2016 12:58 to 12/11/2016 12:58
and then derived them into two columns, date format and time format

Comment: Can you show your code so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your column is datetime/datetime2 data type you can use [DATEPART](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-co/library/ms137586.aspx) function to separate date part from time part.

In the Derived Column Transformation Editor, create two columns and select the `<add as new column option>` use these expressions:

To get the **Date**

```
(DT_WSTR,2) DATEPART("dd", TimestampColumn) + "/" +
(DT_WSTR,2) DATEPART("mm", TimestampColumn) + "/" +
(DT_WSTR,4) DATEPART("yyyy", TimestampColumn)
```

To get the **Time**

```
(DT_WSTR,2) DATEPART("Hh", TimestampColumn) + ":" +
(DT_WSTR,2) DATEPART("mi", TimestampColumn)
```

However if your column is a varchar or nvarchar data type you can use a [SUBSTRING](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms137541.aspx) function to get the date and the time in two derived columns. i.e:

```
SUBSTRING(TimestampColumn,1,2) --> will give you the month
SUBSTRING(TimestampColumn,4,2)--> will give you the day
SUBSTRING(TimestampColumn,7,4) --> will give you the year
SUBSTRING(TimestampColumn,12,5) --> will give you the time
```

Let me know if this helps.